# How to convert timestamp format to 2011-05-10T06:58:00?

Tags: mysql, drupal, timestamp

I have a column in my drupal database called "field_concert_published_value" which is storing the values of the concert publishing (it is a cck field)

I have old records from previous system and there is stored this value as classical timestamp.

I know how to INSERT INTO ... however the format of the date time cck field is unusual. I mean e.g. **2011-05-10T06:58:00** . The letter T between the date and time, so I can not use FROM_UNIXTIME function to convert from my old records to this **yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ss.**

Any advice how to convert my old records in timestamp format to the new one which date time filed is using?

Thanks.

P.S. I need this to be done using SQL statement (MySql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), [FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `timestamp` ) ), '%Y-%m-%dT%H.%i.%s');
```

This page has a good explanation of the date tokens: [MySQL Date Time Formatting](http://www.upwebmaestro.com/mysqldatetime.php).

Comment: Hi, Michael, I don't, what will be the statement? Let say we have timestamp like 1199721572 and I want from this timestamp make a string like yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ss (with the letter T between date and time). What mysql code should I write? Thanks